# How to fetch location from server in each 5 mins recursively and show the current location of vehicle in Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, service

In my app, I am already sending the current location of a bus(basically a device) to the server. This data sending is happening each 5 mins.

Now I am developing another module of the app where I want to show that bus location. So, I need to fetch the bus location every 5 mins from server and display the location in Google Map in Android. This should be like Uber bus tracking ( I mean seamless). Can someone share me a sample code for that?

Thanks,
Arindam

Comment: so what is your real question? how to run task over and over again in 5 mints?

Comment: I need a complete solution sort of code. If i divide it: 1. Need to fetch latitude and longitude using api from server on each 5 mins. Can be done as a service but if can a get better solution. 2. Update that location on map and show the bus movement like uber is showing.

Comment: If there is github project or sample code, it will be great.

Comment: use work manager to run your task in each 5 mint https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics#java

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83a4rYXsDs0

Comment: But if I get the location from server each 5 mins, how can I update the map? I mean a seamless movement of the vehicle.